# How would I use the FlxTrailArea to move an FlxTrail's x and y to be relevant with an FNF character's position similar to the Ronald Mcdonald mod?

Tags: lua, haxe, haxeflixel, lime

[FlxTrailArea official explanation](https://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/addons/effects/FlxTrailArea.html) <- FlxTrailArea

[FlxTrail official explanation](https://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/addons/effects/FlxTrail.html) <- FlxTrail

[YouTube gameplay footage](https://youtu.be/umzxR-o6cjs?t=55) <- The video footage of the described trail movement (red afterimage)

This is relevant to FNF (Friday Night Funkin') and lua/haxeflixel coding.

`var aceTrailArea = new FlxTrailArea();`
<- My incomplete instantiation of an FlxTrailArea.

I'm assuming I have to set the x and y value to a variable and maybe create a function for it..?

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm assuming you could apply this question to an FlxTrailArea AND an FlxTrail... Would it be easier to use an FlxTrail instead of an FlxTrailArea for this situation..?